# when scrolling data in tableview its crashing

Tags: objective-c, ipad

When i am moving the data from tableview cell by one its crashing ..

When my view did loaded my array count is 64

I assign this to number of row `return [categorieArray count];`

and cell configuration

```
cell.textLabel.text=[categorieArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00f8fbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010e45c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f916fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f01366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f00f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Sigma-Aldrich                       0x0000468d -[RootViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 237
    6   UIKit                               0x000977fa -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
    7   UIKit                               0x0008d77f -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
    8   UIKit                               0x000a2450 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
    9   UIKit                               0x0009a538 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    10  QuartzCore                          0x017f5451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    11  QuartzCore                          0x017f517c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    12  QuartzCore                          0x017ee37c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    13  QuartzCore                          0x017ee0d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0181e7d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00f70fbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f060e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00ecebd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00ece240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00ece161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x01203268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0120332d GSEventRun + 115
    22  UIKit                               0x0003242e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    23  Sigma-Aldrich                       0x00001d49 main + 121
    24  Sigma-Aldrich                       0x00001cc5 start + 53
    25  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` - you-re calling a bad method (not implemented) or on a wrong object. What's the line where the application crashes? (should be somewhere in `[RootViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`)

Comment: @applelover post your cellForRowAtIndexPath,noOfRowsInSection Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have an incomplete implementation of your `UITableViewDataSource`, specifically (it seems) you forgot to implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so that when the framework tries and calls it, it fails.

Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: oops i forget to about datasource and delegate methods for the uitableview thanks sergio.

Comment: @sergio "when scrolling data in tableview its crashing" If @applelover failed to implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, how is it that it only crashed when he scrolled? It would crash before the table view showed up... And why the stacktrace he posted is showing a call to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: @albertamg: the second part of your question is pretty clear to me: UIKit is calling a required method, only the method is not found. As to the first part, I would need the code, to try and explain that...

Comment: @sergio: if UIKit tried to call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and did not find the method, the stacktrace would show something like `NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:` (according to my tests) instead of an actual call to the method. That plus the crash only when scrolling makes me think `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` was implemented.